# Can you stop mouse events on specific location in youtube iframe?

Tags: html, css, iframe, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I need to stop all pointer events in youtube iframe and enable only the clicking on the setting s button, is there is a way or workaround to do so?
my approch was to do this :
pointer-events: none;
but all options of pointer events does not work for this purpose.

Comment: You can not access any elements _inside_ the iframe, since it loads from a different origin. If the options the YT API gives you to enable/disable specific parts of the UI aren't enough for what you need to achieve, then you could only try to place (transparent) elements from your page _over_ the iframe in all the relevant places, so that those would "capture" those clicks. Apart from the extra work this might need for different breakpoints, and how easily it might break if YT ever changes their UI, it could also get you in trouble with  "click-jacking" protection systems.